# Was Carolin Gallego the secretary of Donald Trump in 1992?

Tags: donald-trump

[Some people](http://www.ibtimes.com/carolin-gallego-another-fictional-character-donald-trump-created-praise-himself-2607009) seem to believe that this letter to the New York magazine in 1992 was written by Donald Trump, and not his secretary.

> “Based on the fact that I work for Donald Trump as his secretary—and
>   therefore know him well—I think he treats women with great respect,
>   contrary to what Julie Baumgold implied in her article … I do not
>   believe any man in America gets more calls from women wanting to see
>   him, meet him, or go out with him. The most beautiful women, the most
>   successful women—all women love Donald Trump.”
>
> Carolin Gallego December 7, 1992

Is there any record of Ms Gallego  being Mr Trump's secretary at that time?

I relalize that, if she was, it does not prove that she wrote the letter, but am curious as to 1) her existence and 2) her employment at that time

Comment: She definitely exists: https://imgur.com/gallery/GHNgFAd (;-)

Comment: The Internet is all aTwitter with this.  No really "hard" answers, but the [Washingtonian](https://www.washingtonian.com/2017/10/26/trump-carolin-gallego-letter/) claims to have put some real effort into it.  I have no idea how credible they are.

Comment: Does anyone else remember his "personal physician"'s bizarre statement about his health somewhat prior to the election?

Comment: Do you mean [when he](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2016/08/bornstein-trump-linguistics/497840/)  “state[d] unequivocally” that Donald Trump “will be the healthiest individual ever elected to the presidency.”

Comment: And that he weighed 236 pounds.

Comment: I think this is going to be next to impossible to prove the negative.  We can show that there are zero mentions of a "Carolin Gallego" working for Trump in 1992 besides the letter to the editor, and we can show that there was another woman (Norma Foerderer) who was Trump's personal assistant.  But neither of these can be used to claim that Gallego exists.  It doesn't help that the vast majority of google results for "Carolin Gallego" bring up news articles on the supposed "Trump = Gallego" theory, pushing any other results not related to the story off search pages.

Comment: Someone could certainly write an answer that says "there's no evidence that she exists, someone else was Trump's assistant, the writing style looks similar to Trump tweets, and he's done this in the past", but that wouldn't add anything to this discussion that isn't found on a billion news articles online already

Comment: Yahoo's version of the story seems to claim that she exists, but offers no proof, only saying that she was "Executive Secretary to Donald J. Trump The Trump Organisation from December 1991 to October 1993".  Of course, other sources name Foerderer and Rhona Graff as his personal secretary.

Comment: But Yahoo appears to be the only source that has supposedly identified her.  The several other sources I find that refer to her being on the job in that period all credit it to Yahoo.

Comment: @DanielRHicks right, and without a citation from Yahoo, all of those other sources are equally invalid.

Comment: I wish that someone had posted an answer, but as things stand, @DanielRHicks has the closest thing to an answer.